# Webpage is loading while css style is not ready?

Tags: html, css, django

I have a very simple webpage that link two `css` files like this:

```
<link href="style1.css">
<!-- Html code -->
<link href="style2.css">
<!-- Html code -->
```

I notice that when I keep reloading the page, occasionally the page will be loaded without the `style2.css` but then the next second the page will apply `style2.css`.

It doesn't happen to `style1.css`; It always load before the html is rendered.

The reason that why I source two `css` files like this is because I am using `Django global template` so that I the base template will source the `style1.css` and then I can apply the `style2.css` (or other `css`) whenever I want to.

Is it a reason why I see such behavior?

Comment: why not use etiquete "LINK"?

Comment: It is a typo. I modified the question.

Comment: maybe django documentation helps - > https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 1):

CSS stylesheets are not scripts. Include them as follows into the HTML `<head></head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
```

Comment: I use link. I had typo on my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="style1.css"></script>
<!-- Html code -->
<script src="style2.css"></script>
<!-- Html code -->
```

script tag used to load scripting file `javascript` `vbscripts.`

for adding css file use `link` tag.

```
<link href="style1.css"></link>
<!-- Html code -->
<link href="style2.css"></link>
<!-- Html code -->
```

**Complete Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="style1.css"></link>
    <!-- Html code -->
    <link href="style2.css"></link>
    <!-- Html code -->
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, actually I use <link>. I will modify my question.